# Ebean Query incorrect results

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am learning the play framework I am looking to list a number of orders and then after clicking on the order it will give details of the products within. I have the list of orders working correctly (heading model in index class) but when clicking on the order it gives the same product details for every order which is incorrect (show class using product model). Any advice would be great thanks

```
    public Result index(){

            List<Heading> headings = Ebean.find(Heading.class)
                    .where()
                    .eq("CustomerID", "74")
                    .orderBy("DateOrder desc")
                    .setFirstRow(0)
                    .setMaxRows(10)
                    .findList();
            return ok(index.render(headings)) ;
        }


        public Result show(Integer id){
                        List<Product> products = Ebean.find(Product.class)
                        .setFirstRow(0)
                        .setMaxRows(10)
                        .findList();
                return ok(show.render(products)) ;

        }


@Entity
@Table(name="Heading")
public class Heading extends Model {


    @Id

    @Column(name="JobKeyID")
    public Integer JobKeyID;
    @Constraints.MaxLength(50)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="Name")
    public String Name;
    @Column (name="JobNumber", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR")
    public String JobNumber;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="SellingPriceIncTax")
    public Integer SellingPriceIncTax;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="DateOrder")
    public Date DateOrder;
    @Column(name="CustomerID")
    public Integer CustomerID;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "heading")
    public List<Product> product;

    public static Finder<Integer, Heading> find = new Finder<>(Heading.class);


}

package models;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;
import io.ebeaninternal.server.type.ScalarTypeJsonList;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product extends Model {


    @Id

    @Column(name = "ItemKeyID")
    public Integer ItemKeyID;
    @Constraints.MaxLength(50)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    public String ProductName;
    @Column(name = "ItemNumber")
    public Integer ItemNumber;
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "DesignName")
    public String DesignName;
    @Column(name = "JobKeyID")
    public  Integer JobKeyID;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="JobKeyID")
    public Heading heading;


    public static Finder<Integer, Product> find = new Finder<>(Product.class);

}




    @(headings : List[Heading])

@Layout("All Books") {
    <h1> All Books</h1>
    @for(heading <- headings) {
        <a class="btn btn-link" href="@routes.BooksController.show(heading.JobKeyID)">@heading.Name</a>
        <p> JobNumber : @heading.JobNumber</p>
        <p> Price : @heading.SellingPriceIncTax</p>
        <p> Author : @heading.DateOrder</p>
    }

}



@(products : List[Product])


@Layout("All Books") {
    <h1> All Books</h1>
    @for(product <- products) {
        <p> Design Name : @product.DesignName</p>

    }

}



GET     /headings                       controllers.BooksController.index
GET     /headings/:id                   controllers.BooksController.show(id: Integer)
```

Comment: For people who maybe having the same issue I have solved this with the addition of the following line to my show class

Comment: .where().eq("JobKeyID",id)

but if anyone with play experience any comments on anywhere else you can see that could be improved that would be great